# Music from other apps stops playing when my app starts

Tags: ios

When I start my app music from other apps stops playing.

I've tried adding the `setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but the music still stops on FIRST launch. If I start the music and goes back to the app with home button the music will continue to play. Is there any workaround for the first launch issue?

Snippet I've added:

```
// make sure music plays while sounds play.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` is the appropriate thing to use. I'm using precisely that code in one of my apps, and it works as expected - already playing audio from other apps is not stopped when my app launches. `setCategory` returns a BOOL for success; have you tried checking that, or seeing if an error is returned in the `error` parameter?

Comment: @zpasternack Good idea, I'll try to see if I can get something meaningful out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient withOptions:0 error:nil];
```

Or this if above doesn't work:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

EDIT:

If none of the above works for you, you should maybe try set another  category you see fit together with [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/avaudiosessioncategoryoptionmixwithothers) if that works for your use-case.

> Determines whether audio from this session is mixed with audio from
>   active sessions in other audio apps.

Comment: Nope didn't work. I'm wondering if it could be related to a static library which is used for playing some sounds.

Comment: @Warpzit Hmm... not sure, above mentioned should work if you setActive:NO then you can perform changes without accessing the audiosession with current options and stopping other music from playing. You should atleast try disable the other frameworks to make sure. However, check the updated answer if that fits your needs and works out for you maybe?